# Customise FileUpload Helper in Webmatrix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, webmatrix

I've been trying to customise the FileUpload helper in Webmatrix. 
Having managed to style my submit button using Bootstrap by setting 'includeFormTag' to false and setting my own form tags, I really want to have the submit button next to the input.

My code is below. Could someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Many thanks

```
<div class="input-group">
 <form method="post" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:false) 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="myButton">Upload</button>
    </span>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `FileUpload` helper. It provides no value at all. In fact, it hinders because it outputs the file upload control inside a `div` which is difficult to access and therefore affect its behaviour without the use of jQuery or similar. Use an  `<input type="file" />` instead. Then follow the [Bootstrap documentation for inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

`<form method="post" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="myButton">Upload</button>
</form>`

Comment: Thanks Mike I shall look into this. Can you tell me if this a ridiculous question? I'm wondering why someone marked me down on it?

Comment: I don't think it's ridiculous. I wouldn't worry about people who down-vote and scuttle off into the long grass again without having the courtesy to leave a comment to explain why they did what they did. That sort of behaviour adds no value at all to the site, IMO.